# How can I create a dictionary from 2 lists, one representing keys and the other values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

As the question says, I have two lists that look like this:

```
list1 = ["key1", "key2"]
list2 = ["value1", "value2"]
```

I would like to create a dictionary like this:

```
dict1 = {"key1": "value1" , "key2" : "value2"}
```

Is there are an easy way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

```py
my_dict = dict(zip(list1, list2))
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary comprehension is perfect for this:

```
dict1 = {k: v for k, v in zip(list1, list2)}
```

Edit: it seems there is an even shorter solution, as per Sazzy's answer :)